Table Adjustment
I have this table that I wanna apply the following adjustments to :
1.Align the cell content both vertically and horizontally.
2.Add spacing between the cells
3.add padding to all the subcells
4.adjust the cell size such that all cells have more or less the same size
Thank a lot in advance, and this is th Latex code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{c}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    
   
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\hskip-4.5cm\begin{tabular}{ |c{2.7cm}|c{4.88cm}|c{4cm}|c{3.5cm}|c{4.03cm}|   }
 \hline

 
\cellcolor{black!25} \textbf{ML Algorithms}& 
\begin{tabular}{
    | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}p{2cm}
    | >{\sffamily\raggedright}p{2cm}|} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|c{4.05cm}|}{ Supervised learning} \\   \hline

 {\cellcolor{blue!45}Regression} & {\cellcolor{blue!20}Classification } 



 \end{tabular}
 \hline
  
&{\cellcolor{black!50} Unsupservised learning } & {\cellcolor{black!50} Semi-unsupervised learning} &
{\cellcolor{black!50} Reinforcement learning}\\[40pt]
\hline



 
 \cellcolor{black!20} \textbf{Production Volume} & {\cellcolor{black!50} Prototype}&{\cellcolor{black!50} Small series production} & {\cellcolor{black!50} Series production} & {\cellcolor{blue!40} Mass production}\\[40pt]
 
 \hline \
 
\cellcolor{black!20} \textbf{Production System}   & {\cellcolor{black!50} Planning}&{\cellcolor{black!50} Ramp up} & \multicolumn{2}{|c{7.95cm}|}{\cellcolor{blue!45} Operation}  \\[40pt]

\hline
 
\cellcolor{black!20} \textbf{Uncertainty Quantification} &   {\cellcolor{black!50} Frequentist inference} &
\multicolumn{3}{|c{12cm}|}{\begin{tabular}{
   |c{5cm}|c{5.8cm}|} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|c{11.2cm}|}{ Bayesian inference} \\   \hline

 {Traditional ML} & {Deep learning}\\[7pt]
 \hline
 {\cellcolor{blue!45} Gaussian process regression} & {\cellcolor{blue!45} Bayesian neural networks} \\[12pt] \hline



 \end{tabular} } \\[40pt]
 
 \hline
 


 
\cellcolor{black!20} \textbf{Uncertainty Estimation
Algorithms} &{\cellcolor{black!50}Extrinsic methods} & 


\multicolumn{3}{c{12.1cm}|}{\begin{tabular}{
   |l{3.5cm}|c{2m}} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|c{11.1cm}|}{ Intrinsic methods} \\ \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{black!50}Data uncertainty only} & \begin{tabular}{
    | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}p{1.4cm}
    | >{\sffamily\raggedright}p{5.78cm}|} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|c{7.5cm}|}{ Data and model uncertainty} \\   \hline

\cellcolor{black!50}Ensemble methods   & \begin{tabular}{
    | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c{2.4cm}
    | >{\sffamily\raggedright}c{2.4cm}|} 
  \multicolumn{2}{|c{4.7cm}|}{Bayesian approaches}   \\ \hline 

 {\cellcolor{blue!45}Bayesian neural networks} & {\cellcolor{blue!45}Gaussian process regression} 

 \end{tabular}  \\ \hline




 \end{tabular}  \\ [5pt] \hline
 
 \end{tabular}}





\\[80pt] \hline
 
\cellcolor{black!20}\textbf{Uncertainty Quantification Problem}    &{\cellcolor{black!50}}Forward problem &\multicolumn{3}{|c{12cm}|}{\begin{tabular}{
   |c{3cm}|c{3.5cm}|c{3.8cm}| } 
  \multicolumn{3}{|c{11cm}|}{ Inverse problem} \\ [5pt]  \hline

 {\cellcolor{black!50}Bias correction only} &{\cellcolor{black!50}Parameter calibration only} & {\cellcolor{blue!45}Bias correction and parameter calibration}\\[14pt]
  \hline
\end{tabular} } \\[40pt]
 
 \hline
 
\cellcolor{black!20} \textbf{Metrology}  &\multicolumn{2}{|c{3.02cm}|}{\cellcolor{blue!20}|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}Traceability}\\[40pt]

\hline
 
\cellcolor{black!20}\textbf{Industrial Sector} & {\cellcolor{black!45}Chemical}  & {\cellcolor{black!45}Food and beverages}   & \multicolumn{2}{|c{5.95cm}|}{\cellcolor{blue!45}Construction ......} \\[40pt]

\hline
 
 
\end{tabular}

 \caption{Virtual Measurement Based on Probabilistic Machine Learning}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}




\end{document}

I tried different align commands but nothing worked and for the spacing and padding I am confused on how to get godo results

Have a look at the tabularray package. This makes adjusting cells much easier.
